# ReactJS/Redux - Root component page is rendered on refresh from any page

Tags: reactjs, url, redux, react-router

My app has a default route that loads the component `HomePage` on the `localhost/` path in dev mode.

But when I refresh the app from any page, the home page is displayed instead, even though the URL in my browser displays `localhost/any/other/path`. If I then navigate manually through the app to the `/any/other/path` path, the browser's URL becomes `localhost/any/other/path/any/other/path`.

**It's like the router always thinks the current path is `/` on refresh.**

What could the issue be? I'm using React 16 and `"react-router-dom": "5.1.2"`.

My routes are laid out as follows:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path="/proxy" component={ProxyPage} />
        ...
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

And my Redux `router` reducer is as follows:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: window.location.pathname
})

// Reducers
combineReducers({
  ...
  router: connectRouter(history),
  ...
})
```

In the store the `router` reducer starts as follows, even when loading a URL:

```js
router: {
  action: "POP",
  location: {
    hash: "",
    pathname: "/",
    query: { },
    search: "",
    state: undefined
  }
}
```

Edit: Simplified my use case to be more straightforward, added more information

Comment: It's better if you also add some code example of your router setting (For more accurate/specific answer).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Silly question - what do you mean by router setting exactly ? the Route components inside a Switch, etc?

Comment: Yes. Also, add some code examples. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

I had changed the default `basename` argument in my browserHistory's configuration, which did not work as I understood (I was trying to fix a lack of redirection issue on app launch).

Removing the `basename: window.location.pathname` line fixed my (self-inflicted) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but my hunch is that this behavior is more related to using Redux and ConnectedRouter than your routes, which look fine to me. 2 questions:

1. Are you using hot reloading?
2. If you take this same code and run it in a non-redux app with BrowserRouter, what happens?

Comment: I am not using hot reloading. If it helps, I've edited my question to have a more straightforward scenario, the issue is present even with totally normal routes. And I've added some Redux-related information.

Answer (score 0):

When true, redirecting will push a new entry onto the history instead of replacing the current one.

Redirect push to="/somewhere/else" /

Are you using the Redirect push in your code?

Answer (score -1):

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path="/proxy" component={ProxyPage} />
        ...
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```